# How to switch to other url, after clicking a button/link using BrowserRouter

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a component which is main and contains login and register actions. What I want is to switch to path `/dashboard` after clicking buttons. I declared the Routes in index.js, so my main component just needs to push `/dashboard`, Then the Dashboard component will be rendered. Searches recommend using history.push(path) but I couldn't import history properly since it said history is not a function.
Could you help me understand where is the history object and how can I use it?
I use react-router-dom v5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to access `history` object, you need to wrap the component with `withRouter` by importing it from `react-router-dom`.

`export default withRouter(your component);`

[More on history object](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/history.md)

You can also user `<Link>` to perform the navigation.
[Check this out for Link.](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/api/Link.md)